# Django OperationalError at /books/add_review_to_book

Tags: python, django, operationalerror

I'm stuck for 2 days on this error,I'm new to Django and I am trying to write  reviews for books.When I open the review form and type some text and after that submit it, I get this error -

```
OperationalError at /books/add_review_to_book/8
table books_review has no column named book_id.
```

Everything looks okay for me heres the code:

My models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' - ' + self.author


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)


class Review(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', related_name='reviews')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

My views.py:

```
def add_review_to_book(request, id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReviewsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.book = book
            review.save()
            return redirect('book_detail.html', id=book.id)
    else:
        form = ReviewsForm()
    return render(request, 'books/add_review_to_book.html', {'form': form})
```

My forms.py:

```
class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('author', 'text')
```

My html that takes the form add_review_to_book:

```
{% block content %}
        <hr>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'add_review_to_book' id=book.id %}">Add review</a>
{% for review in book.reviews.all %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="review">
        <div class="date">
            {{ review.created_date }}
        </div>
        <strong>{{ review.author }}</strong>
        <p>{{ review.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <p>No comments</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I deleted migrations and made them again, I still get the same error when I try to write a review. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Result after running .schema books_review in dbshell -

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "books_review" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "text" text NOT NULL);`

Still `table books_review has no column named book_id` :(

Comment: did you done `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Yes, I did.I deleted them after the error and made them again.Still the same error.

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: I'm using SQLite3

Comment: please, look is `__init__.py` inside your `migrations` and 
can you try `./manage.py dbshell` and inside the dbshell `.schema books_review`, please add result to the question in code formated

Comment: Updated.Still the same -  table books_review has no column named book_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i can see, you have no two fields `book` and `author`, possible you broke migrations, try to do next steps:

1. dump data `./manage.py dumpdata auth.user > users.json`
2. `./manage.py dumpdata books.book > book.json`
3. remove sqlite database `rm db.sqlite3`
4. remove migrations folder `rm -rf books/migrations`
5. recreate books\migrations `mkdir books/migrations`
6. create init.py `touch books\migrations\__init__.py`
7. create new migration `./manage.py makemigrations`
8. apply migrations `./manage.py migrate`
9. load data `./manage.py loaddata *.json`
10. test your code

hope it help you

Comment: Did exactly as you said and now I can't create authors and books, but the exception this time is - OperationalError at /books/

no such table: books_author

Comment: CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such table: books_book - When I did the 2nd step.

Comment: what is your app name?

Comment: App name is books

Comment: try start from step 3 until step 8, if you will have any messages write it here

Comment: No errors while running them now, the operationalerror is gone too, now i get 404 when I submit the review for a book

Comment: you need create new `user` and `book`

Comment: I createsuperuser  and book, after that I pressed Review, I mean I can't access books If I'm not logged and can't write review if I don't have a book.

Comment: you have new trouble, `return redirect('book_detail.html', id=book.id)` need replace `book_detail.html` on your detail book url name

Comment: But, I don't use url in urls.py for book_detail.html since I include the add_review_to_book.html in the book_detail.html, should work like that. <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'add_review_to_book' id=book.id %}">Add review</a> thats in my book_detail.html, the full code of book_detail is on my question.

Comment: cool!, glad to help, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Took me awhile, I'm new to this community too, thanks once again!